# Importing CSV file into SQL Server with commas in a cell

Tags: sql-server, number-formatting

I'm trying to import a CSV file into SQL Server Management Studio.  The file has a column that has times listed in minutes.  Some of them are over 1000 minutes, and are listed using commas (ex: 1,470).  SQL Server sees these commas in the cell, and thinks they belong to the next cell over, which throws off all the following rows.  I've tried to adjust the delimiter in the import wizard with no success.  I've also thought about trying to find and replace within Excel, but the files are too large to import.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: In the first instance, are you able to export instead with a different delimiter or as quote delimited? Comma is one of the worst delimiters. I often use tab or `~`. If you can't then you'll need to enlist some tricks to clean the data. Can you post some sample lines. One correct line and one with the issue?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? How are you trying to perform the import? SQL Server 2017 and later support (properly encoded) RFC 4180 CSV files via [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#importing-data-from-a-csv-file) and [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql#format). RFC 4180 format files permit commas, quotes and line breaks in field data - so long as the file is encoded correctly.

Comment: 1.  I can't export from anything, because I haven't been able to open it fully.  Excel will let me import up to a million rows of it, but that won't help me, because I won't have the full dataset when I export it.

Comment: 2.  I'm using SQL Server 2018.

Comment: I can't seem to post a pic, but I'll try to post a link to the dataset.   It's the Divvy_Trips_2019_Q3.zip spreadsheet from here: https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html   It's from the Google Data Analytics Certification on Coursera.

Comment: I've found another way to import the data..  Originally importing them one month at a time was giving me an error for some of the months.  However, some of them did import fine.  I read through the error codes and discovered that there were some dashes in the field data that MSSMS didn't like.  So I used find and replace in excel (which I could use because the datasets were smaller) and got rid of the dashes and was able to import them using the monthly datasets.  Now i just have to join them and start analysis.  Thanks anyway!